# Is there a way to delete every button in a for loop on Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, window

I have a for loop that produces 4 buttons and they each direct to one function. This function needs to start by clearing all of the buttons on the page. Can you please help with this?

```
x_position = 160
for i in range (5,9):
      u = urllib.request.urlopen(actorimages[i])
      raw_data = u.read()
      u.close()
      
      im = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
      im = im.resize((120,180),Image.ANTIALIAS)
      photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
      
      photo1button = tk.Button(image=photo,width=120,height=180,compound="c",
                               borderwidth = 0,
                               highlightthickness = 0,
                               command = lambda i=i, b=photo1button: actorInfo(i,canvas,b),
                               relief = "flat")
      photo1button.image = photo
      photo1button.place(x=x_position,y=351)
  
      canvas.create_text(
                x_position, 552,
                text = actorName[i],
                fill = "#ffffff",
                anchor=tk.SW,
                tag = "actorheading",
                font = ("Roboto", int(9.0)))

      x_position += 158
      


def actorInfo(i,canvas,b):
  b.place_forget()
  canvas.delete("actorheading")
```

Comment: Use a list to store the buttons and then you can use this list inside `actorInfo()` to remove all the buttons.  Also you can use `text` option to show the *actorName* instead of creating a text item over the button (actually the text items will be covered by the buttons and so they are not visible at all).

Comment: @acw1668 how would i create the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *list* to store all the references of buttons, then you can go through this list to remove the buttons inside `actorInfo()`:

```py
buttons = []  # list to store the created buttons
x_position = 160
for i in range (5,9):
      u = urllib.request.urlopen(actorimages[i])
      raw_data = u.read()
      u.close()

      im = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
      im = im.resize((120,180),Image.ANTIALIAS)
      photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

      photo1button = tk.Button(image=photo,width=120,height=180,compound="c",
                               borderwidth = 0,
                               highlightthickness = 0,
                               command=lambda: actorInfo(canvas),
                               relief = "flat")
      photo1button.image = photo
      photo1button.place(x=x_position,y=351)
      buttons.append(photo1button) # add button to list

      canvas.create_text(
                x_position, 552,
                text = actorName[i],
                fill = "#ffffff",
                anchor=tk.SW,
                tag = "actorheading",
                font = ("Roboto", int(9.0)))

      x_position += 158

def actorInfo(canvas):
    # remove all buttons (note that they are not destroyed) stored in the list
    for b in buttons:
        b.place_forget()
    canvas.delete("actorheading")
```

Note that I have removed the `i` and `b` arguments in `actorInfo()` as it is not necessary. Actually you can remove the `i` argument as well.